# Assertions and Outputting Specific URLs

Tags: webdriver, java, junit

Here's what I've done so far.

```
@Test
public void test() {

    String[] list = {};     

    for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/" + list[i]);    

        boolean text = driver.getPageSource().contains("meta");

        if(!text) {

            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is, this test returns false. It does not find the meta data.

Any idea why?

Comment: Welcome to SQA, user3249785.  Please edit your question to describe what you have done so far.  Is this your first time to use JUnit?  First time to use Webdriver?

Answer (score 1):

You can match your text, if it is false, you can save the url. Try following:

```
String[] pages = {"http://google.com","http://yahoo.com"};
ArrayList<String> pagesWithoutMeta = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean isMetaPresent= false;
for (int i=0;i<pages.length;i++){
    String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@name='Description']")).getAttribute("content");
    isMetaPresent = text.contains("your text");
    /*Or you can do following:
     *isMetaPresent = driver.getPageSource().contains("your text");*/
    if(!isMetaPresent){
        pagesWithoutMeta.add(pages[i]);//If meta is not present add the url in an arraylist, which you can use or print later.
    }
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Here's what I ended up using.

Comment: See above in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache JMeter for this, it can handle things much faster as it doesn't spawn a real browser and sends HTTP requests (GET in your case) only.

You'll need:

1. [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler - to send requests
2. [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) - to read URLs from file
3. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) - to assure that metadata is present in the page source

There is also a [WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) for JMeter if you would prefer using a real browser.